# reloading data in an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, extjs

I have an Ajax request sent by jQuery, and the returned xmldata is loaded onto a data store:

```
$.ajax ({
    url:..,
    data:..,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'xml',
    success: function (xmlResult,xhr){
        d=$(xmlResult);
        store = new Ext.data.XMLStore({
            data:d,
            ....
        )}
    }
})
```

Is there anyway I can refresh the xmldata on user request like calling the .reload() function?

Answer (score 3):

Just encapsulate that ajax request in a function and call the function whenever you want to refresh the data.

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax ({
        url:..,
        data:..,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'xml',
        success: function (xmlResult,xhr){
            d=$(xmlResult);
            store = new Ext.data.XMLStore({
                data:d,
                ....
            )};
        }
    });
}
```

You can trigger it with a button click...

```
<!--HTML-->
<button id="reloadButton">Reload</button>

//JS
$('#reloadButton').click(function(){
    getData();
});
```

or even set to reload using a timer

```
var t=setTimeout("getData()", 5000); //Refresh every 5 seconds
```

Comment: Cool.. didnt think of putting it in a function. that worked..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you either add this to a click event or use setInterval to keep it refreshing automatically